# Does this converge in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm asked whether $X_{1}, X_{2}, ...$ converges in probability where $P\left(X_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\right)=1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ and $P\left(X_{n}=n\right)=\frac{1}{n^{2}}$.  I think I have the solution, but some of the steps I just feel uncomfortable about, so I wanted to check that they're OK.  Here is my solution:

I guess that this converges to the degenerate distribution $X=0$.  Then if $\varepsilon > 0$

$$P(|X_{n}-X|>\varepsilon) = P(|X_{n}|>\varepsilon) $$

$$=P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\right|>\varepsilon\right)P\left(X_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\right) + P\left(\left|n\right|>\varepsilon\right)P\left(X_{n}=n\right)$$

For large enough $n$ we get this equal to

$$0\cdot P\left(X_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\right) + 1\cdot \frac{1}{n^{2}}$$

which goes to 0.

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.